# Pyspark - Regex_Extract value between forward slash (/)

Tags: regex, pyspark, databricks

I created 3 expressions with the idea of extracting some values between forward slash (/) with substring_index, but I know that I can create that simpler with **regexp_extract** function. The scenario is:

- Expression: '**T- 41231/REGULAR/041293**'

And I want to extract the following values:

1. the first value: **41231** where I created this: `.withColumn("ACode",  substring_index(substring_index(col('column1'), 'T- ', -1), '/', 1))`
2. the second value: **REGULAR** where I created this:  `.withColumn("Bcode", when(col('column1').like('%/%'), substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(col('column1'), 'T- ', -1), '/', -2), '/', 1)) .otherwise(lit("")))`
3. the third value: **041293** where I created this: `.withColumn("Ccode",  when(col('column1').like('%/%'), substring_index(substring_index(col('column1'), 'T- ', -1), '/', -1)) .otherwise(lit("")))`

Do you know how to make it simpler?

| column1 | Acode | BCode | Ccode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T- 41231/REGULAR/041293 | 41231 | REGULAR | 041293 |

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `split`?

you can:

```
.withColumn("Acode", split("column1", "/")[0])
.withColumn("Bcode", split("column1", "/")[1])
.withColumn("Ccode", split("column1", "/")[2])
```

Comment: it's quite hard to understand the logic of your problem..
for the first one `split(split("column1", " ")[1], "/")[0]` might work but again, what is the logic here...